# iterm + tmux isn't allowing me to scroll up with the mouse

Tags: terminal, iterm, macos

I recently rebuilt my system and everything works except I can't scroll my (iterm2) terminal window back to look at commands and output that have scrolled off the screen.

Without tmux I can scroll but with tmux I can't

When using vim this isn't an issue as I can scroll back within vim.

For basic terminal (which I don't normally use) the behavior is a little different in that the current line scrolls back to show previous commands, but just that line, not the whole window.

My terminal settings include: [image]

I do use tmux and I have a detailed .tmux.conf  **However** I have removed these settings, applied with `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`,. seen the changes applied (back to default tmux setting) and still have the issue

My settings include

```
set -g mouse on
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The recent release of tmux 2.1 changed some of the configuration options. This bit of code (taken from [here](http://joehanchoi.com/quick-fixes-for-tmux-2-1-on-osx/)) restores the previous functionality:

```
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"  
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
```

Add/place these in the `~/.tmux.conf` file

Apply with `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: Great.  Updated to mention `.tmux.conf``

Comment: Works on one mac and one Ubuntu machine without errors but another mac says unknown `unknown key: WheelUpPane` and `unknown key: WheelDownpane` it has the same osx version (Yosemite) and has same version of iterm2 (2.1.4) and tmux (1.9a)

Answer (score 10):

One cause of this is the "Secure Keyboard Entry" feature of iTerm.

To solve this problem, you can go with <kbd>iTerms</kbd> -> <kbd>Secure Keyboard Entry</kbd>, and de-select that item.

[image]

I came across this issue with my Logitech MX Master 2S as well, and unfortunately other solutions mentioned here didn't work to me.

Comment: oh this one worked for me with the MX Master 2S, why would that secure keyboard entry option ever disable scrolling with the mouse wheel. Thanks :)

Comment: It's 2021 and this still works / is still broken with the MX Master 3 and iTerm2 3.4.4 :-/

Answer (score 8):

In iTerm2 all you need to do is to go to Preferences > Profile > Terminal and check ‘Save lines to scrollback when an app status bar is present’.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I enabled “Mouse Reporting” on iTerm2.
Under *iTerm Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal Setting*, tick the "Enable mouse reporting" checkbox.